# Cannot establish HttpURLConnection in Android

Tags: android, http

```
URL url = new URL(versionPath);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), versionPath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
c.setRequestMethod("GET");
c.setDoOutput(true);
c.connect();

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "HttpURLConnection Complete!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Exception catched, first versionPath text is correct, cannot see the "HttpURLConnection Complete!" text. When I copy the same "versionPath" on the browser inside my device, I can see the content. I have INTERNET permission in my manifest. Any idea?

Comment: Note: it's android.os.networkOnMainThreadException

Comment: ok I got it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11282610/cannot-connect-using-httpconnection-in-android

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, i believe all the classes are part of android and no external libs are used.

```
public static JSONObject getJsonFromUrl(String urlString) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IllegalStateException, IOException, JSONException {
    // set the connection timeout value to 10 seconds (10000 milliseconds)
    final HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 10000); //how long to wait for connection
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 10000); //how long to wait for response
    // Create a new HTTP Client
    DefaultHttpClient defaultClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
    // Setup the get request
    HttpGet httpGetRequest = new HttpGet(urlString);
    // Execute the request in the client
    HttpResponse httpResponse = defaultClient.execute(httpGetRequest);
    // Grab the response
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
    StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        json.append(line);
    }

    // Instantiate a JSON object from the request response
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json.toString());

    return jsonObject;
}
```